# sed replace regex with regex

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

This sounds like a really banal question, and it's bugging me dearly.

I have a text file, generated by python, that contains a list of host names and ip addresses in the following format:

```
host46.provider.com = 192.168.0.1
```

However, because the file was generated asynchronously, there's a few strange errors in the output. I'm getting lines that look like this:

```
us9831.provider.com = 262.99.124.183us9832.provider.com = 121.92.213.10
```

The problem is that it hasn't inserted a newline between the two instances. I've ascertained that (fortunately) the naming convention of the nodes **doesn't allow for a number to come before a letter, unless it's before a dot (`.`)**

So what I neeed to happen is:

- find an instance where a number comes before a dot
- add a newline between the two

I can't figure out how I'll get `sed` to maintain the regex match, and copy that over to the next regex.

I've tried this:

```
cat eg | sed '/[0-9][a-z]/s/[0-9][a-z]/[0-9]\n[a-z]/'
```

and I have tried this:

```
cat eg | sed "s/[0-9][a-z]/\n/"
```

Is `sed` the right tool? Should I be using `awk`?

Any suggestions would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: The `unless it's before a dot (.)` part of the statement `doesn't allow for a number to come before a letter, unless it's before a dot (.)` is confusing. Why isn't `doesn't allow for a number to come before a letter` enough? What does a number before a letter that's also a dot (or whatever that means) look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `unless it's before a dot (.)` part of your requirements means but if your requirement is  really just that a number can't be immediately before a letter then if your sed supports `\n` to produce a newline in the replacement text:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\n\2/' file
us9831.provider.com = 262.99.124.183
us9832.provider.com = 121.92.213.10
```

Otherwise with any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\
\2/' file
us9831.provider.com = 262.99.124.183
us9832.provider.com = 121.92.213.10
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: @LewisFarnworth if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily. That way, you don't have to repeat the solution in an acknowledgement statement posted as answer (which would be considered incorrect posting on this site, btw).

Comment: @LewisFarnworth you're welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "us9831.provider.com = 262.99.124.183us9832.provider.com = 121.92.213.10"| sed "s/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/&\n/g`"

output

```
us9831.provider.com = 262.99.124.183
us9832.provider.com = 121.92.213.10
```